# Unable to delete in %WinDir%\System32\OOBE\Info\Backgrounds

Tags: windows, powershell, lock-screen, sccm

I've got a PS script (deploying through SCCM) that needs to delete the items in %windir%\System32\OOBE\Info\Backgrounds, but it outright refuses to do so.

If I do it manually, it works perfectly.  But if it's executed by the system, it sets the permissions, but never deletes the files.

```
& takeown /f "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds" /a /r /d y
& icacls "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds" /grant administrators:F /t /c
& del /q /f "C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\*"
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: What permissions does the process running as system have on this folder?

Comment: What error does the script throw? You might get better error reporting if you use the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

Comment: The process is being run as the System account.  If I drop the `/a` from the `takeown` command, the owner is set to `$computername`.

As for the error, there is none.  I've done `Remove-Item -Verbose | Out-File log.log`, but there is no output.  I've done `Start-Transcript transcriptlog.log` as well, and most commands will output everything, but nope.

Comment: Is this deployed as application or program? If program and on a 64bit OS keep in mind that the sccm execmgr will only be a 32bit process so any access to system32 would be redirected to syswow64 instead

Comment: @Syberdoor It's as a Package/Program.  The program is this: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File Remove-Backgrounds.ps1`

Comment: If you call it like this is it will be 32bit redirected by the wow64 handler. Could you try to call it like this "C:\Windows\Sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File Remove-Backgrounds.ps1" (this path will not exist if you call it in explorer but once it is executed by the sccm it will work) and see if this changes anything?